# How to "gather like terms" if it isn't all just addition and subtraction.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the very fundamental and root stages of math and algebra, we are often taught to "gather the like terms" in an expression by just putting what looks the same together. I personally am not too far from that stage. And every single example in those lessons are with generic expressions such as 3x + 5 + 8x + 2. Many times, even the meaning of "term" is defined as just what is being added or subtracted.

However, I have, after scouring the internet, not come across *any* examples of terms without addition and subtraction. Expressions such as simply "3a x 8 x 9a x 3 / 4a" If the definition I stated above is used, then the whole expression is technically one big term. In this case, it is logical that we could collect like terms by just moving the terms around.

So then how would we even define a term? And why is what seems like such an obvious question to me never ever touched upon?

Comment: A term is a part of an expression. Is that all your question is about? Why did you tag this with ODEs?

Comment: I tell my students that a "term" is just a chunk of math symbols separated from other chunks by addition or subtraction. "Term" is not a formal term. t's just something that sometimes makes it easier to talk about math.

Comment: As part of your scouring did you try searching for "definition of terms in mathematics"? If you did you would have come across [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/term.html),[this](https://www.splashlearn.com/math-vocabulary/algebra/term) and [this](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(mathematics)). Those are just the first three results.

Comment: @John Douma Yes I did actually come across both of those articles. However, they felt contradictory. One says a term can only be a number, a variable, or both multiplied. The other says it is just part of an expression. So then is something like 5/x a term? That was my logic.

Comment: No, $\frac{5}{x}$ is not a term. Terms are numbers, variables and their products. There is no contradiction. When you add and subtract terms you get expressions. If this stuff interests you then I suggest you study mathematical logic or, if you like programming, Backus-Naur form [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). This definition of term is standard.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks for the info :). However, genuine question, if it is a standard definition why have the two people above stated different definitions? Or are there different interpretations of some sort?

Comment: @HouZeng I can't speak for anyone else but mathematics is about rigor, not interpretation. A term is well defined as is an expression and a sentence in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

When we gather like terms one important example is polynomials in one variable like $f(x)=3x^2+2x+1$ or $g(x)=x^3-x^2$ where the terms are each different depending on the exponent. Here if we add $f(x)+g(x) = 3x^2+2x+1 +x^3-x^2$ we gather like terms which gives us $f(x)+g(x)=3x^3+2x+1$.

However when we use this example and we multiply them as $f(x)g(x)$ the issue is that the exponents change so we have different terms and can no longer group them in the same way. To see this we calculate $$f(x)g(x)=(3x^2+2x+1)(x^3-x^2)\\=3x^2(x^3-x^2)+2x(x^3-x^2)+1(x^3-x^2)\\=3x^5-3x^4+2x^4-2x^3+x^3-x^2\\=3x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2$$

and we can see that the multiplication creates different combinations of terms which can add up to things not present in either term originally. So when you're gathering like terms it's always addition and subtraction because this case is so important.

Comment: Thank you! Also, if 3x is a term, 3/x (division) isn't a term to be gathered?

Comment: @HouZeng For division you use negative exponents so $3/x = 3x^{-1}$.

Comment: $\frac{3}{x} + \frac{4}{x} = (3 + 4) \frac{1}{x} = 7 \cdot \frac{1}[x} = \frac{7}{x}$

Comment: So for lower levels division isn't really factored in due to its nature I'm guessing?

Comment: @HouZeng Addition and multiplication have associativity which is $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$ and $a(bc)=(ab)c$ while subtraction and division are not. For this reason we add negatives and multiply reciprocals rather than actually using subtraction and division. So $\frac1x$ is always shorthand for $x^{-1}$ and $x-y$ is always shorthand for $x + (-y)$.

Comment: So would division be a "term" or is the word term, like someone said, not a formal definition?

Comment: @HouZeng I would consider $x^{-1}$ a term that's different from say $x$ or $x^2$. When you use fraction terms they're called Laurent polynomials. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial